# No volume groups found - CentOS

Tags: centos, hyper-v, lvm, grub

I have migrated a CentOS 5.11 server from VmWare to Hyper-V and when trying to boot the server. I'm getting the following error messages:

"`No volume groups found`" "`"VolumeGroup00" not found`" and consequently the other messages you see on the screenshot.

[image]

I have booted the VM from a live CD I had in hand and I can see & mount the volume group (lv in the volume group) fine.  Here's the `vgdisplay` command output:

[image]

You can see the grub contents on the start of the first screenshot. Why do you think this is happening? Any tips?

edit: `hd0` is mapped to `/dev/sda` as it should be.

Comment: How are the disks attached to the vm? Hyper-V seemed to prefer ide disks when I last looked into it. Are you using the Hyper-V drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, just after creating a bounty, I was able ti fix it by rebuilding the initrd as explained here: https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CreateNewInitrd

Comment: ok, that would say some driver was missing in your old initrd

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! If the link ever dies, the short version is: boot from CD in rescue mode, `chroot /mnt/sysimage`, `mkinitrd -f -v /boot/initrd-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)`

Answer (score 0):

boot from cdlive and use the command `vgchange -ay VolGroup00`  and Now Mount the `mkdir /mnt/root && mount /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /mnt/root`

Now you can check your `lvm filter` with `grep filter /mnt/root/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`

Other thing you can check is `grep volume_list /mnt/root/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`

Comment: Tried it, did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix, you'll just need to reconnect those volume groups.

1. Boot into rescue mode.
2. Select 'shell' Start Shell
3. chroot into your image `chroot /mnt/sysimage/`
4. Re-connect your lvm volumes `vgchange -ay`
5. change your root password if you need.
6. Reboot

additional steps may be required to fix fstab, but this should do the trick without much additional information, I had mounted a HBA iSCSI drive to a RAW Mapped drive by performing these additional steps.

1. Remove _netdev from /etc/fstab
2. Remove iSCSI Boot options from /etc/grub.conf

Booting the first time will take a while. (it did for me anyway, different scenario but similar situation.)

Good Luck!

Comment: I tried that, it did not work.

Comment: any warnings when you ran this command?
what is your fstab output?

Comment: no there were no error messages, it worked fine. But I just booted into the same thing again and again.

I just posted an answer I found on an IRC channel. FSTAB only included tmpfs devpts, sysfs and proc.

Comment: Well I'm glad you figured it out and posted your results.